# Inverse of function is itself?

Tags: functions, inverse

Let$f(x) =$
\begin{cases}
k(x) &\text{if }x>3, \\
x^2-6x+12&\text{if }x\leq3.
\end{cases}
Find the function $k(x)$ such that $f$ is its own inverse.

I thought that that inverse would just be the inverse of $x^2-6x+12$ would be $3+\sqrt{x-3}$, however, after graphical analysis, I found the answer to be the conjugate: $3-\sqrt{x-3}$.
Is this the right answer, and if so, why is it negative instead of positive?

Comment: If $y=x^2-6x+12$ then $x=3\pm\sqrt{y-3}$; we take $x=3-\sqrt{y-3}$ to get $x\le3$

Answer (score 2):

If $y=x^2-6x+12$, then $x=3\pm\sqrt{y-3}$; we take $x=3-\sqrt{y-3}$ to get $x\le3$.

Comment: Thanks! Is the variable x or y? Meaning $x=3-\sqrt{y-3}$ or $y=3-\sqrt{x-3}$?

Comment: For the inverse function, I was writing $x$ as a function of $y$

Comment: My english is terrible. So the final answer is $x=3-\sqrt{y-3}$ or $y=3-\sqrt{x-3}$? Many thanq

Comment: $k(x)=3-\sqrt{x-3}$

Answer (score 0):

$$f^{-1}-3=\pm\sqrt{x-3}$$
You have to choose '$-$' because $x^2-6x+12=(x-3)^2+3\ge3$ and hence $f^{-1}$ must be $\le 3$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were very close.

Missing k(x) is this: k(x) = 3 - (sqrt( 4x - 12 ))/2

Plot it and you will see, that now f(x) = inv f(x).

Have a nice day.